# Numpy warning file installed not on PATH

Tags: python, numpy, path, windows-10

today I install python 3.9.5:

- For all user
- Customize install that save on program files\python39
- automatically create PATH

then I open CMD from start and write pip install numpy, but there is warning that
numpy installed on app data/ roaming/python and that is not on PATH

cause my python PATH was on program files, so why numpy installed on app data?
Please help me

Comment: What do you mean by 'Customize install that save on program files\python39'? You installed numpy into that python directory? Is there a site-packages file under file\python39 that has numpy in it? I believe that would be like 'libs\site-packages\numpy' or something

Comment: Oh thats 'program files'\python39

Comment: Ok, sorry I misread about numpy. But, I think you might have an easier time using `venv` package for managing installations. Thats what I've used on windows. See here: https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/venv.html

Comment: package installations that is. `venv` is for handling python packages, not the python 3.9 installation